# How can I copy inputstream into two copies

Tags: java

I need to hash the inputstream during upload to ensure the integrity of the file. How can I copy the inputstream into two copies and the size of the file is more than 10GB. It need faster time to hash and copy

Comment: You could just wrap something like [Guavas `HashingInputStream`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashingInputStream.html) around whatever you are using. That way you don't need to handle two different streams.

Comment: Fast time than what ? Can you [edit] your question to show your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options.

1. `Files.newInputStream`, hand that off to your hasher algorithm, obtain the hash, then start over to send. This is the best option if it is highly useful to have the hash available during/before the upload. It requires reading the bytes off of disk twice, of course.
2. Use an existing implementation of a stream that hashes on the fly, such as guava's [`HashingInputStream`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashingInputStream.html), or write something like this on your own (it's not particularly difficult to do so).

You can't easily have 2 inputstreams that can both be fully streamed through whilst only causing the file to be read once, because the 'user' of an inputstream decides how 'fast' you go through, and you can't have 2 separate lines of code both be in charge.

Hence, one of the two processes needs to not be an inputstream and instead have its control reversed: Instead of allowing the code to ask the inputstream for more data (by calling one of its `read` methods), you'd have some code that is invoked by the inputstream with: Hey, I just read this data because the 'primary' driver asked for it, before I hand it off to the primary driver, anything you need to do here?

The hashing code should be this secondary driver, because it can trivially deal with 'here are X bytes but we are not done yet please process it'.

Here is an example of what that would look like. Note that `FilterInputStream` by default just forwards all calls directly to the stream you wrap.

```java
public class HashingInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
  private final MessageDigest hash;
  public HashingInputStream(InputStream base) {
    super(base);
    hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
  }

  @Override
  public int read() throws IOException {
    int v = super.read();
    if (v == -1) return v;
    hash.update((byte) v);
    return v;
  }

  @Override
  public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    int r = super.read(b);
    if (r == -1) return r;
    hash.update(b, 0, r);
    return r;
  }

  @Override
  public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    int r = super.read(b, off, len);
    if (r == -1) return r;
    hash.update(b, off, r);
    return r;
  }

  public byte[] digest() {
    return hash.digest();
  }
}
```

your upload code wraps the inputstream, e.g:

```
try (var in = Files.newInputStream(pathToYourFile)) {
  var hashing = new HashingInputStream(in);
  hashing.transferTo(yourOutputStream);
  var hash = hashing.digest();
}
```

And you'll get your hash at the end; the file is only read once.

Comment: I agree with you, but in the project I am only allowed to use JDK8. I can do it when I use HashingInputStream, but I have OOM when I convert the inputStream to bytes. The reason is that my data is too big and I converted it. The reason is to verify whether the file has been modified through the hash, so I need to use this inputStream twice, but I have no way to do it now

Comment: @gxt I think you're missing the point of the filterinputstream bits. You read the file once by filling a buffer. As you read the bytes, they are hashed, an placed in the buffer. At each bufferful you can write your output to your file so you don't have to store all of the bytes in memory.

Comment: @gxt the snippet I showed you is vanilla JDK8. I couldn't possibly cause an OOME; if you're running into OOME it's you explicitly attempting to turn the whole ordeal into a gigantic byte array.